# Submit Form with Complex DataType to Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

This is my model

> Model

```
public class XPersonContent
{
    public string PersonType { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

}

public class XViewModel
{
    public List<XPersonContent> XPersonList { get; set; }
    public string XContent { get; set; }
    public sbyte CommentEnabled { get; set; }

}
```

> Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddXViewModel ( XViewModel testModel)
{

}
```

> Form using MVC that submits to controller

```
function submitForm() {

    var xpersonContent=[Object { Id=2934109,  Type="us"}, Object { Id=2913974,  Type="us"}, Object {Id=2912159,  Type="us"}]
    var xContent= "test";
    var CommentEnabled= false;

    var dataString = {
        XPersonList:xpersonContent,
        XContent: xContent,
        CommentEnabled: true
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AjaxPostDemo/AddXViewModel",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataString ),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ajaxPostMessage").empty();
            $("#ajaxPostMessage").html(data.Message + " : " + data.Date);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}

> Question
```

How do i build the object XViewModel to pass back to the controller. i have them in three different variables
i have tried to do this
    dataString = {
        XPersonList:xpersonContent,
        XContent: xContent,
        CommentEnabled: true
    };
but its not working..

Comment: Where does the error occur (client or server)? What does it say? (this is the kind of information you should include in the question)

Comment: there is no error the server does not get any value in the controller, everything in null

Comment: Your ajax `data` value is `JSON.stringfy(datastring)`. There are two problems here. 1) the function is `stringify` not `stringfy`. 2) variable names are case-sensitive, so it should be `dataString`. These should have caused a javascript error in the client's console.

Comment: still have same problem

Comment: try intercepting your parameters before entering the controller - there you can evaluate, adjust - and catch problems

Comment: i can see the values in firebug, when server gets it there is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
in my ajax request
SMH

Answer (score 0):

Try change to this

```
var xpersonContent=[{"XPersonContent": {"Id": 2934109, "Type": "us"}}, {"XPersonContent": {"Id": 2913974, "Type": "us"}}, {"XPersonContent": {"Id": 2912159, "Type": "us"}}]
```